# Plot a custom xlabel in a semilogx graph

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I need to plot a custom xlabel in Matlab, in a semilogx graph.
I have to display the xtick as:
-10^3 or -10^2 etc. not -0.001 or -0.01.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually wondering why you don't get the right results from the beginning. Have a look at this: [link](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-NZN20/index.html)

Comment: Surely you mean `-10^-3`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {'10^-3', '10^-2'})
```

Comment: Closing parenthesis missing :-) Also, note that the size of the cell array has to match that of `get(gca,'Xtick')`, otherwise the labels are reused cyclically

Comment: No it must be: - 10^3 not 10^3

Answer (score 0):

The docs(http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16KCT/) recommend this sort of approach:

```
set(gca,'XTick',x) 
set(gca,'XTickLabel',sprintf('%3.4f|',x))
```

So your question becomes how do we convert 0.001 -> 3 and 0.01 -> 2. That's `-log10(x)`

```
set(gca,'XTick',x) 
set(gca,'XTickLabel',sprintf('-10^%i|', -log10(abs(x))))
```

Dealing with the sign is slightly more complicated.

Here's my attempt:

```
set(gca,'XTick',x);
s = '-';
signs = s(ones(size(x)));
signs(x>=0) = ' ';
set(gca,'XTickLabel',sprintf('%c10^%i|', signs, -log10(abs(x))));
```